# PDOStatement query with subqueries returns empty result

Tags: php, postgresql, subquery, pdo

I have the following PHP code which whows a weird behaviour. The system is backed by a PostgreSQL database, PHP version is 5.3.15.

```
    $sql = "SELECT ce.id FROM calendar_events AS ce
        WHERE ce.rowid = :rowid
        AND ((SELECT count(*) FROM calendar_events_attendees AS cea WHERE cea.event_id = ce.id AND cea.status <> 'D') > 0
            OR (SELECT count(*) FROM calendar_events_globalfnbl AS ceg WHERE ceg.event_id = ce.id AND ceg.status <> 'D') > 0)";

$stmt = db_prepare($sql); // Creates a PDOStatement
$stmt->bindValue(":rowid", $rowid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rv = $stmt->execute();

if($rv) {
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

The query executes without errors but the function returns an empty array. There are definitely rows to find in the database, if I execute the query in pgAdmin (placeholder replaced by ID in question of course), it returns the rows I want to get.

I managed to find out that the sub-queries are the problem here. If I comment them out and use the following query, the rows are returned. But of course this does also return rows which I try to filter out with the sub-queries.

```
$sql = "SELECT ce.id FROM calendar_events AS ce
        WHERE ce.rowid = :rowid";
```

Does PDO simply not support this type of sub-queries or is there any  error in my code I cannot find?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PDO supports sub-queries, actually it does not care if your SQL contains sub-query or not, the problem is in the SQL query itself, not the PDO. Try to run this query via command line or other IDE to see if it is executed properly and if there are results returned.

Comment: As I already wrote in the question, I executed the query with pdAdmin III. To be sure I just copy-pasted the code from here to pgAdmin III, replaced the :rowid placeholder with an actual ID and executed: Returned 5 rows, just as expected.

Comment: The statement returns an array containing all of the remaining rows in the result set: An empty array is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure, so what is the content of yours, true,false,0... (try with print_r($rv) and print_r($stmt->fetchAll))?

Comment: Output of var_export(): array ()

Comment: Found a problem in my code that caused this behaviour, question is now obsolete. See my answer below.

Comment: I have never seen `tableName as ALIAS before`. Is it not supposed to be `select t.id as id from tablename t`?

Comment: The "AS" is optional with table names. It works both ways but I like it more to use the "AS" as it makes the query easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a problem with PDO but with my code itself. After double checking the code calling the above function again and again I found some statements that set the status to 'D' for the rows in question BEFORE the above code was executed.

So this question is now obsolete, sorry for wasting your time folks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your framework, but your `COUNT(*) > 0` subqueries appear to be equivalent to `EXISTS (...)` subqueries (which might be faster as well, since they don't have to count all satisfying tuples)

```
SELECT ce.id 
FROM calendar_events AS ce
WHERE ce.rowid = :rowid
AND ( EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM calendar_events_attendees AS exa
                WHERE exa.event_id = ce.id AND exa.status <> 'D'
                )
     OR EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM calendar_events_globalfnbl AS exg
                WHERE exg.event_id = ce.id AND exg.status <> 'D'
                )
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but did not fix my problem.